# What is returning class when use "return this"?

Tags: java

I started learning Java and I couldn't understand one of examples in "Thinking in Java" book.
In this example author represent, as he state "simple use of 'this' keyword":

```
//Leaf.java
//simple use of the "this" keyword

public class Leaf {
    int i = 0;
    Leaf increment() {
        i++;
        return this;
    }
    void print() {
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Leaf x = new Leaf();
        x.increment().increment().increment().print();
    }
}
```

And when above code is working as indeed, I cant understand what `increment()` method is returning.

It's not variable `i`, it's not object `x`? I just don't get it. I tried to modify program to understand it (like replace `return this` with `return i` or `print x` instead of `i`), but compiler shows me errors.

Comment: That's one way of implementing a [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: `this` always refers to the current instance. For instance you could write `this.i` instead of `i` in `increment()`.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) will help you understand `this` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for your replay @Whymarrh, but take into consideration, that I just started learning Java and I would like more "for newbie" explanation. I tried to go trough that wiki article, but it sounds for me like chainees

Comment: @Pshemo I reed your reference and after that I think that using `this` makes code less readable, at least for newbee like me. I think I understand now a bit more of it

Comment: I agree (and Java creators also) it is less readable, that is why instead of `this.fieldOfThisClass` you can just use `fieldOfThisClass`, just like in case of `i` (you don't have to use `this.i++`), this is implicitly added by compiler to make code more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return this;
```

will return the current object i.e. the object which you used to call that method. In your case object `x` of type `Leaf` will be returned.

Comment: That's what I tought, but then why replacing 'System.out.println("i = " + i);' with System.out.println("i = " + x); is not working?

Comment: You Leaf class will need a `toString()` method

Comment: @FlenMK just use this again here. with System.out.println("i = " + this.i);

Comment: @FlenMK: Because values are not variables.  The object could have any of trillions of different names, all at once (given sufficient memory to run a program that large).  It doesn't know which of those names you used to call it through.

Comment: x only exists in the main function, while i is a member of the class.  You need to read up on scope.

Comment: @developerwjk I think your answer give me a clue. I cant change `i` into `x`, because method `print()` doesn't know object `x` as it is local method for class `Tree` and there is only initialized(?) variable `i`. Is my tought right?

Comment: @FlenMK You are correct. `x` is local to `main` and therefore `print()` does not know about it.

Answer (score 0):

`this` represents the instance of the class from which the method was called.  So returning `this` means returning this instance of the class.  So, as the return type shows anyway, the increment() method is returning a `Leaf` and its returning the instance in which the increment() method was called.

This is why you can call:

```
x.increment().increment().increment().print();
```

Because with each call to `.increment()` you are getting another Leaf on which you can call all the methods inside Leaf again.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a keyword that is referencing the current `Leaf` instance. When you create your first `Leaf` with `Leaf leaf = new Leaf ()` it creates a singular instance of `Leaf`

Esentially,  you are returning the `Leaf` instance that is calling `increment()`

Answer (score 0):

`return this;` returns the instance of the class it is acting on. So every call of `increment()` is returns the same instance and then it calls `increment` again. You can keep on calling `increment()` as :

```
x.increment().increment().increment().increment().increment().increment()...
```

Comment: So this is same like i would write method `increment` as `void increment() {i++}` and in `main()` use `x.increment; x.increment;...` insted of above?